# Styled Components with bracket doesn't work properly in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

Styled Components with bracket doesn't work properly in Next.js
I'm using typescript, styled-components with Next.js

package.json

```json
    "dependencies": {
             "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.2",
             "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.2",
             "next": "12.0.4",
             "react": "17.0.2",
             "react-dom": "17.0.2",
             "react-inlinesvg": "^2.3.0",
             "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
             "redux": "^4.1.2",
             "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
             "styled-components": "^5.3.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
             "@types/node": "^16.11.10",
             "@types/react": "^17.0.37",
             "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.15",
             "eslint": "7.32.0",
             "eslint-config-next": "12.0.4",
             "typescript": "^4.5.2"
    }
```

.babelrc

```json
    {
    "presets": ["next/babel"],
    "plugins": [
       [
         "babel-plugin-styled-components",
         {
            "ssr": true, 
            "displayName": true, 
            "preprocess": false
         }
       ]
    ]
    }
```

_document.tsx

```js
import React from "react";
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
import { ServerStyleSheet } from "styled-components";
class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: (App) => (props) =>
            sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
        });

      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
          </>
        ),
      };
    } finally {
      sheet.seal();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

palette.ts

```js
const palette = {
    Alert: ["#FF8080"],
    Font: ["#333333"],
    Background: ["#F7F7F7"],
    // Gray : Black - Medium - Light
    Gray: ["#EDEDED",
           "#C4C4C4",
            "#A1A4AF"],
    // Blue : Dark - Light
    Blue: ["#0057FF",
            "#849EFF"],
}

export default palette;
```

but in a certain situation, like using Styled Components with bracket, and the components in the bracket were imported, styled-components cannot apply any of it.

(it can render the imported component, but cannot apply any additional styles)

RegisterForm.tsx

```js
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import styled from 'styled-components';
    import RoundButton from '../../components/common/RoundButton';

    const RoundButtonWithMarginTop = styled(RoundButton)`
        margin-top: 3.75rem;
    `;

    const RegisterForm = () => {
         ...
         <RoundButtonWithMarginTop>Next</RoundButtonWithMarginTop>
         ...
    }
```

components/common/index.tsx

```js
    export * from './Header';
    export * from './Responsive';
    export * from './RoundButton';
```

components/common/RoundButton.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import palette from '../../lib/styles/palette';

const RoundButtonBlock = styled.button`
    width: 100%;
    background-color: ${palette.Gray[1]};
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 3rem;

    cursor: pointer;

    &:hover {
        background-color: ${palette.Gray[0]};
    }
`;

const RoundButton = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <RoundButtonBlock>
            {children}
        </RoundButtonBlock>
    );
};

export default RoundButton;
```

[how button appears on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b97V1.png)

How can I solve this problem?
Please give me the solution.

Comment: Can you post the `palette` how it looks like?

Comment: const palette = {
    Alert: ["#FF8080"],
    Font: ["#333333"],
    Background: ["#F7F7F7"],
    // Gray : Black - Medium - Light
    Gray: ["#EDEDED",
           "#C4C4C4",
            "#A1A4AF"],
    // Blue : Dark - Light
    Blue: ["#0057FF",
            "#849EFF"],
}

export default palette;

It's just a simple palette. that's all

Comment: Can you update your question adding the palette?

Comment: question updated.

Comment: If you console log before the definition of `RoundButtonBlock`. What can you see from the console?

Comment: When entering a page using RBB, the message input using console.log() is output as it is.